# svn checkout fails with error svn cleanup required

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When checking out source code on same server at same location at same time checkout fails with error 
cleanup required

is there a way we can avoid this. Is this due to some race condition.

Answer (score 1):

The wording that sticks out to me is

> ... on same server **at same location** ...

If you're doing a checkout in the same location, you're pretty much asking for errors. To avoid this, checkout into a new directory each time and then do `svn update` commands on your checked out folder. You only need to check out once.